# How do I access the name, lat, lon variables within the getISS() function?

Tags: javascript, function, discord.js

I'm new to java script but can anyone tell me how I would access the `name`, `latitude`,`longitude` variables within the `getISS()` function? I'm creating a bot in discord.js and I am able to get the data I want to show in `console.log();` but now I need to access it in the bot `.on('message'` event section, currently the output just shows name is undefined.

```
//ISS api_url
const iss_api_url = 'https://api.wheretheiss.at/v1/satellites/25544';
async function getISS() {
  const response = await fetch(iss_api_url);
  const data = await response.json();
  var name = data.name;
  var lat = data.latitude;
  var lon = data.longitude;
};

//ISS command
bot.on('message', async message => {
  if (message.author.bot) return;
  if (!message.guild) return;
  if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;
  const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/g);
  const cmd = args.shift().toLowerCase();

  if (cmd === 'iss') {
    message.channel.send('name: ' + name)
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is [the scope of your variables](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp). There are heaps of ways to fix this, assuming both your functions are working, you can just smash them together.

```js
//ISS command
bot.on('message', async message => {
  if (message.author.bot) return;
  if (!message.guild) return;
  if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;
  const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/g);
  const cmd = args.shift().toLowerCase();

  if (cmd === 'iss') {

    const response = await fetch(iss_api_url);
    const data = await response.json();
    var name = data.name;
    var lat = data.latitude;
    var lon = data.longitude;

    message.channel.send('name: ' + name)
  }
});
```

Comment: Ah perfect, I tried to combine them earlier and I did it completely wrong. Thanks for the quick response :D